# Show that $X = \mathbb{E}(X)$ almost surely for any random variable $X$ with variance $0$

Tags: probability, proof-verification, random-variables

> Theorem: $X$ is a random variable, let $\mu = E[X]$  if  $V(X)=0$ then $X = \mu$ almost surely.

Proof:
$V(X)=0 \implies E[(X-\mu)^2]=0$.
For all integer $K \ge 1$, by Chebyshev's inequality $P(|X-\mu| \ge {1 \over k}) \le {k^2 \cdot V(X) = 0}$

Does that conclude our theorem by saying $k$ arbitrarily large? I have the impression that is not correct, and would have to show instead : $P(|X-\mu| \ge 0) = 0$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\{\omega \in \Omega; |X(\omega)-\mu| \geq 0\} = \Omega$ and therefore

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu| \geq 0)=0$$

cannot hold true (by the very definition of a probability measure, we have $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$!).

---

The statement $X=\mu$ almost surely is equivalent to saying that

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu| \color{red}{>} 0)=0. \tag{1}$$

To prove $(1)$, note that by the $\sigma$-additivity of the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$

$$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|>0) = \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \{|X-\mu| \geq 1/k\} \right) \leq \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(||X-\mu| \geq 1/k)=0.$$

Comment: I see how this works! So my argument was incomplete